# toString() method not printing the correct values of object

Tags: java

I'm following a book and I have a `Point` class which defines a point and I am trying to display the values. I've been looking around for a while now, whatever I do it always displays [0,0] here's my code.

```
  class Main {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Point point = new Point(10, 20);
        System.out.println(point.toString());
    }      
  }

  class Point {

    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
      x = x;
      y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're never initializing class members `x` and `y` actually. So they're initialized as 0 automatically hence the `[0,0]` output.

`x = x` means parameter x = parameter x which does nothing.

use `this.x = x;` instead so `Point` class member `x` will be set.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in Constructor as below :-

```
class Point {

private int x, y; // These x and y are member of Point class

public Point(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

public String toString() {
  return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
 }
```

You are not initializing x and y of Point class.
In toString() method you are printing x and y of Point class which are not initialized and hence taking default value of 0 i.e. 0 is default value of integer.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your constructor:

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
      x = x;
      y = y;
    }
```

In your case you do not initialize class fields. To do that, use `this` keyword and it should look like:

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
```

Otherwise you are dealing with parameter `x` and `y` variables only.

Answer (score 1):

use the this keyword for the separation of local variable and instance variable. in your parameterized  constructor jvm is not able to initialize the instance variable because it gets an ambiguity problem between local and instance variable. And instance variable in java gets implicitly initialized if u we are not initializing that's why you are getting [0,0] as the output.

here is the code..

class Main {

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    Point point = new Point(10, 20);
    System.out.println(point.toString());
}
```

}

class Point {

```
private int x, y;

public Point(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

public String toString() {
  return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Constructor` for the `Point` object:

```
    public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
```

You will need to put `this.x` to indicate you are setting the value of the `Point` object's `x` variable, not the `x` argument passed into the constructor.

The updated, functional code is below:

```
 class Main {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Point point = new Point(10, 20);
        System.out.println(point.toString());
    }      
  }

  class Point {

    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
    }
```